# Multiple table inner join not showing any results

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, join

I'm using visual studio sql database to inner join 3 tables to one main table.

The main table is `Event` and the `PK_EventsID` is linked to the `FK_EventsID` of the other 3 tables (`StudentCompetition`, `ImmersionTrip`, `IndustryCollaboration`)

I tried using inner join with 2 tables (`Event` and `StudentCompetition`) and it works, but when I add another table (`Event`, `StudentCompetition`, `ImmersionTrip`) it does not display anything even though there is an inner join. The column names appear, but the data doesn’t.

Similar column names are `startDate`, `endDate` and `eventID` while the remaining are different. I would also like to know how to group similar column names together

I'm planning to join more then 10 tables together for a search function.

SQL Query

```
SELECT     
            Event.eventName, 
            Event.eventID, 
            StudentCompetition.competitionName,           
            ImmersionTrip.immersionName
FROM       
            Event 
INNER JOIN  StudentCompetition ON Event.eventID = StudentCompetition.eventID 
INNER JOIN  ImmersionTrip ON Event.eventID = ImmersionTrip.eventID
```

Comment: And what is your current statement? Can you create a http://sqlfiddle?

Comment: If nothing is showing it's because there are no rows that satisfy the join conditions of at least one of your INNER JOINs.

Comment: Please share your SQL Query

Comment: @HiralNayak i have added the query

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins?rq=1 first. It explains why inner joins can bring or not bring rows back. TLDR: Inner join is ALWAYS a FILTER.

Comment: @PreetSangha Thanks it help be understand better and solved the problem